# Catch private browsing website address in Android

Tags: java, android

Is there any kind of a method to catch the website URL when user browse using private browsing in an Android device using JAVA program?

Comment: What do you mean by private browsing? I wasn't aware there was any incognito browsing. But anyways, unless apps make this information available, no you cannot do that.

Comment: I mean private browsing facility which is provided by Android browser (ex: firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like it would pretty much defeat the purpose of private browsing, so I'd say: No, and if you found a way, it would be a bug that should be patched.